# Creating a do statement that has the properties of a while statement

Tags: c#

Has been solved. Was trying to create a do statement that would not do anything until the while was checked. Was solved by simply putting an if statement before the do statement.

Using a do statement and anything else you might need, write the equivalent of:

```
while (b) {
    s;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Wow, I did not know C# hat the "do" statement..

Comment: are you trying to reinvent the C# do{}while(); loop

Comment: please improve quality of your question else every one will do downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for

```
if(b)
{
    do
    {
        s;
    }
    while(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is a standard part of the language:

```
do
{
s;
} while (b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you have a code that uses do..while loop and you want to replace it with a "regular" while loop.

That is not so simple as you say in your example. The difference is that do..while will always run at least once, and check the condition after it's completed. While loop may not run at all.